# How to mate two flat pieces of wood at a point about which both can rotate?

Tags: wood, joints

I apologize if this question has been asked or the answer is obvious. I am unfamiliar to the terminology so searching things up is a major difficulty.

I have two flat, long pieces of wood and I want to 'mate' their ends such that both can rotate about that point. I call it a 'rotating joint.' The two pieces of wood would be overlapping. Here is a video of what I am attempting to build:

https://fredericphilips.wordpress.com/projects/swarm-robots/hardware/gripper-design/

The 'joints' can be seen in the four areas, two on each arm.

I would appreciate help determining what components I need and how they come together.

After research, what I believe I need is a bolt, a bearing/bushing and a nut. I would drill a hole, insert the bearing, insert the bolt through the bearing, and tighten with a nut.

Answer (score 3):

I would not use a bolt for this, although you can. There are various ways to do this. The simplest just requires a rod and two push caps.

Drill a hole through the wood and sand it with a fine circular file to fit a rod. Cut the rod to size using (for example) a cutoff disk. Get two push caps and use them to secure the rod/axle. Push caps look like this and you can find them in any hardware store:

[image: push cap]

They are also called "roller caps". To make a smoother action you can insert a bushing in each piece of wood, but that is probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a roto hinge - you can buy it from Rockler

Comment: Hi Jeff, as it stands it not considered a good answer by the bot.  Please paste a picture of it and a link to the store.